# SQL Timeout via .NET Client but no timeout when same sql executed directly against database

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlclient

We have an intermittent issue whereby our web app locks up when executing a specific stored procedure. When this happens, the same stored procedure using the same user/pass can be executed fine from SSMS but causes the web app to hang. The only way to fix it is to drop and recreate the stored procedure.

To rule out nested transactions etc I extracted calling the stored proc to a console application (still using the .NET SQL Client) and that also hangs.

I checked in SQL SQL Activity Monitor when this happens and there were no blocking transactions. Is there anything else I can try?

Thanks

Comment: Have you ruled out parameter sniffing?   http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html